# Как в переменную String занести содержимое графического файла, а потом извлечь назад

Tags: android, java

Суть в том, что есть таблица в БД содержащая два поля String (KEY и VALUE). Поле KEY содержит название файла, а поле VALUE его содержимое. С текстовыми файлами все замечательно, извлекать из полей данные и создавать файлы на устройстве. Из данной таблицы формируем:

```
Map<String, String>;
```

А затем:

```
     try
     {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> file : mapPref.entrySet())
        {
            File outputFile = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + file.getKey());

            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFile);

            out.write(file.getValue());
            out.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error with copying files", e);
    }
```

Из массива сохраняем файлы на устройстве. 
Как внести в переменную графический файл, как потом его от туда извлечь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Жостко... Первый вопрос возникает, а зачем же так извращенно?

Ну если очень надо то можно например так:

1. Извлекаем из `Bitmap` байты через `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`
2. Массив байтов переводим в строку через String - ну например через `StringBuilder` или можно форматнуть в Hex или в Base64
3. Пишем

Теперь чтение:

1. Строку форматируем в byte[]
2. Массив байтов переводим в `Bitmap` через `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`

**Update** Все таки подумай ибо кошерный способ хранения двоичных данных в БД это через BLOB, а не так как расписано у тебя

Comment: @Barmaley, Спасибо!